# Перевод строк из массива на разные языки

Tags: php, массивы, wordpress, json

Использую для вывода сообщений в формах с кучей разных вариаций и проверок примерно такую запись:

```
echo json_encode(array("code" => "not-success","msg"=>"$userdata is null or undefined"));
```

И часть формы:

```
<script>
function test(){
    ...
    jQuery.ajax({                   
        ...
        success : function(response){
            jQuery('#message').html('<div class="test">' + response.msg  + '</div>');
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Как лучше всего их переводить в мультиязычных сайтах? Или как записать иначе, без существенных изменений форм, чтоб строка синхронизировалась в файл перевода (например, в Loco Translate для WP).

Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для перевода сообщений существуют [функции gettext](https://wp-kama.ru/function-tag/localize) `__()`, `_e()` и т.п. В них указывается текстовый домен плагина или темы.

На основе текстовых доменов формируются файлы .po/.mo перевода. Их можно редактировать и в Loco Translate.

При работе с мультиязычным сайтом, плагин интернационализации (WPML, Polylang) переключает локаль (язык) сайта, и перевод текста в `__()` выбирается из .mo файла для текущего языка.

В вашем случае

```
echo json_encode( array( "code" => "not-success", "msg" => __( "$userdata is null or undefined", 'my-text-domain' ) ) );
```

Comment: Как же я мог так затупить... Писал `_е()`, вместо `__()`. Потому и в ошибку выпадало. Потому и с вопросом пришел. Дополните ответ измененным кодом из примера обернув `$userdata is null or undefined`, для обучения будущих поколений и приму как готовый.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку!

Comment: Добавил пример кода в ответ.